# How to redirect a webpage to another webpage after a certain duration?

Tags: python, html, flask, redirect

```
@app.route("/")
def loading():
    # return render_template('loading.html')
    return '<h1> hello it is loading page</h1>'
    time.sleep(3)
    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/home')

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return '<h1> hello it is home page</h1>'
```

Hello, Sir, I want to redirect a webpage to another webpage after a 3second delay to show the contents of the first webpage then the second. In this project, I am using the `flask` library of python but I unable to do that. I also use the `sleep` method but it doesn't work.

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can use the sleep function? https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep

Comment: yes sir I had  tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not work.

```
@app.route("/")
def loading():
    # return render_template('loading.html')
    return '<h1> hello it is loading page</h1>'
    time.sleep(3)
    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/home')
```

You are returning the data:

```
return '<h1> hello it is loading page</h1>'
```

and then you are waiting for 3 secs.

```
time.sleep(3)
```

and doing another return (redirect) again

```
return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:5000/home')
```

You should include some javascript in your `loading.html` template.

and include this script:

```
<script>    
     window.setTimeout(function(){

       // Move to a new location after 3 secs
       window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/home";

       }, 3000);

 </script>
```

your final code should be:

```
@app.route("/")
def loading():
    return render_template('loading.html')

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return '<h1> hello it is home page</h1>'
```

In `loading.html` file

Include this:

```
<script>    
     window.setTimeout(function(){

       // Move to a new location after 3 secs
       window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/home";

       }, 3000);

 </script>
```

So when you visit root `/`, loading.html page will be displayed and after 3 secs, you will be redirected to `/home` page.

You can increase or decrease the duration after which you would like to redirect by increasing or decreasing the value in the `setTimeout` function above.

```
3000 = 3 secs
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind help. I had tried your code and it works properly. and I also understand where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the redirect function correctly. In Flask you must use:

```
return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Make sure that you import `url_for` with

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
```

Comment: sir, I had tried it but it doesn't give me output after 3 second

Comment: what happens after 3 secs

Comment: I now noticed that you will have to do this in js. Because you cannot have 2 return lines function in one fucntion